# Type не дружит с Switch?

Tags: c#, switch

Пишу данную конструкцию(пример):

```
public static void StartAllPool(Type t = null)
{

    switch (t)
    {
        case typeof(Pool):
            StartPool();
            break;
        case null:
            break;
    }

}
```

t в Свиче подчеркивается красным с ошибкой:

**Выражение switch или оператор case должны иметь тип bool, char, string, integral, enum или соответствующий тип с возможным значением NULL.**

Но ведь Type может содержать null, тогда в чём проблема?

Comment: Type чем из перечисленного является? bool, char, string, integral, enum, bool?, char?, string?, integral?, enum? Соответствующий тип - соответствующий чему тип? Это тип соответствующий типу из перечисленного списка. Type в нём нет.

Comment: А зачем Вам вообще switch в Вашем примере? Чем if (t != null) { } не годится? Не знаете как извратиться?

Comment: @Sergey if (t != null) тут не подойдет, так как в дальнейшем есть необходимость не только на 1 тип проверять.

Comment: Ну тогда так надо делать: `if (t == typeof(Pool)) { ... } else if (t == typeof(OtherType)) { ... } else if (t == typeof(AnotherType)) { ... }` С каких пор такая запись считается негодно?

Comment: @Sergey Потому и хотел построить через Свич, для того что бы избежать кучи else if`ов

Comment: Ну да. Куча кейсов, брейков смотрится лучше, при это ещё и уводя лесенку кода за правую границу экрана.

Comment: Используйте полиморфизм в чистом виде

Comment: @klutch1991 полиформизм в моей реальной задаче вроде не подойдёт.

Comment: @BwehaaFox, тот ответ, который вы приняли, как раз решает вашу задачу с использованием полиморфизма.

Comment: @klutch1991 я выбрал его, потому что, там, в первом абзаце есть конкретный ответ на вопрос. В своей задаче я передаю в параметры тип что бы не передавать строку, что бы при изменении типа класса через рефакторинг(или как его там) не приходилось менять строки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Под "соответствующий тип с возможным значением null" подразумевается `Nullable<bool>` / `bool?`, `Nullable<char>` / `char?` и остальные `Nullable<T>` для типов, перечисленных в сообщении об ошибке.

`System.Type` в этот список не входит.

В принципе `switch` по `Type` или по TypeCode - это code smell, обычно означающий что вы должны использовать объекты вместо типов + виртуальные функции, и код должен выглядеть вот так:

```
public static void StartAllPool(ISomeStartable startable) 
{
    startable.Start();
}
```

или

```
public static void StartAllPool(ISome some) 
{
    this.Start(some.DoWork);
}
```

где `ISomeStartable.Start()` и `ISome.DoWork()` - методы, специфические для конкретного типа.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class TypeSwitch
    {
        Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> matches = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();
        public TypeSwitch Case<T>(Action<T> action) { matches.Add(typeof(T), (x) => action((T)x)); return this; }
        public void Switch(object x) { matches[x.GetType()](x); }
    }

    public static void TestTypeSwitch()
    {
        var ts = new TypeSwitch()
            .Case((int x) => Console.WriteLine("int"))
            .Case((bool x) => Console.WriteLine("bool"))
            .Case((string x) => Console.WriteLine("string"));

        ts.Switch(42);
        ts.Switch(false);
        ts.Switch("hello");
    }
```